# Laravel 5.4: loop through array and minus quantity from each object until quantity reach 0 stops

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5.4

I need to loop through array and minus `needed_quantity` from each object

ex. `needed_quantity = 22`

and there is three objects in this array, each object quantity = 10

so it will be something like this.

1. take 10 pieces from expire_date = 2019-03-02 inventory will become 0
2. take 10 pieces from expire_date = 2019-03-10 inventory will become 0
3. take 2 pieces from expire_date = 2019-03-11 inventory will become 8

Here is the array

```
foreach ( $orderProducts as $order_product ) {
                    //This the quantity in order details.
                    $orderQuantity = $order_product->quantity;
    $currentInventors = Inventory::whereProductId( $order_product->product_id )->get()->sortBy( 'expire_date' );

    if ( $currentInventors != null ) {
        foreach ( $currentInventors as $currentInventory ) {
            $takeQuantity = $currentInventory->inventory - $orderQuantity; //10-15 = 5
            if ( $currentInventory->inventory >= $orderQuantity ) {
                Inventory::whereId( $currentInventory->id )->update( [ 'inventory' => $takeQuantity ] );
                break;
            } elseif ( $currentInventory->inventory < $orderQuantity ) {
                Inventory::whereId( $currentInventory->id )->update( [ 'inventory' => 0 ] );
                //$takeQuantity = $currentInventory->inventory - $orderQuantity; //10-15 = -5
                $newQuantity = $orderQuantity - $currentInventory->inventory; //15-10 = 5
                if ( $currentInventory->inventory >= $orderQuantity ) {
                    Inventory::whereId( $currentInventory->id )->update( [ 'inventory' => $newQuantity ] );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I update I get all the three object values `0`

Update array

```
Collection {#715
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => Inventory {#744
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "product_id"
        1 => "inventory"
        2 => "expire_date"
      ]
      #attributes: array:6 [
        "id" => 10
        "product_id" => 857
        "inventory" => 10
        "expire_date" => "2019-03-02"
        "created_at" => "2019-03-07 11:13:21"
        "updated_at" => "2019-03-27 11:16:01"
      ]
    }
    1 => Inventory {#745
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "product_id"
        1 => "inventory"
        2 => "expire_date"
      ]
      #attributes: array:6 [
        "id" => 13
        "product_id" => 857
        "inventory" => 10
        "expire_date" => "2019-03-10"
        "created_at" => "2019-03-10 16:53:21"
        "updated_at" => "2019-03-27 11:16:01"
      ]
    }
    2 => Inventory {#746
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "product_id"
        1 => "inventory"
        2 => "expire_date"
      ]
      #attributes: array:6 [
        "id" => 16
        "product_id" => 857
        "inventory" => 0
        "expire_date" => "2019-03-11"
        "created_at" => "2019-03-10 17:01:14"
        "updated_at" => "2019-03-27 11:16:01"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Include an array we can work with

Comment: @Andreas Here you are I updated my question.

Comment: With an array we can't use. Great.

Comment: @Andreas Updated if you need something else please point me what do you like me to proved.

Comment: What variable represents `needed_quantity` in this code? What is `$orderQuantity`? Why an `elseif` that has the exact opposite of the `if` condition?

Comment: @04FS thanks for asking, here you are `needed_quantity` is an integer (ex. 22) coming from another `foreach` loop I will update my code to show you this too, and it's the same same `$orderQuantity` and about `elseif` it's a try to make the value 0 if the `$orderQuantity` is greater than the `$currentInventory->inventory`. I will update my question kindly review the updated question.

Comment: _“and about elseif it's a try to […]”_ - my point was that you don’t need an `elseif`, if the condition is the _exact opposite_ of that of the preceding `if`, a simple `else`without any further condition achieves the same thing in such a case. If `$currentInventory->inventory >= $orderQuantity` was not the case, then the current inventory can _only_ be less than the ordered quantity, there is no other, third possibility …

Comment: @04FS I believe you are right, but any way this will not fix the issue I have now yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution I wint with.
My fault I was not decreasing the `$orderQuantity` each time in looping.

```
$orderProducts = OrderDetail::whereOrderListsId( $deliveryList->order_lists_id )->get();

foreach ( $orderProducts as $order_product ) {
    //This the quantity in order details.
    $orderQuantity = $order_product->quantity;
    //Here we selected the oldest expire date of the same product in the inventory.
    $currentInventors = Inventory::whereProductId( $order_product->product_id )->get()->sortBy( 'expire_date' );
    if ( $currentInventors != null ) {
        foreach ( $currentInventors as $currentInventory ) {
            $takeQuantity = $currentInventory->inventory - $orderQuantity;
            if ( $currentInventory->inventory >= $orderQuantity ) {
                Inventory::whereId( $currentInventory->id )->update( [ 'inventory' => $takeQuantity ] );
                break;
            } else {
                $orderQuantity = $orderQuantity - $currentInventory->inventory;
                Inventory::whereId( $currentInventory->id )->update( [ 'inventory' => 0 ] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now works fine.